# MS Access Count same items with multiple columns based on date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with the following fields, ID, Username, Application, and Last Access date.  For example..

```
1, user1, app1, date 
2, user1, app2, date
3, user2, app1, date
4, user3, app3, date
5, user4, app1, date
6, user5, app2, date
```

I would like to create a table with application counts for all dates, last 30 days, last 90 days..  For example...

```
app1, 3, 1, 0
app2, 2, x, y
app3, 1, u, v
```

First column is the application, Second column is the count for all dates, next column within the last 30 day, etc..

Normally I really try to figure this stuff out on my own, but I am completely lost and missing something...   Your help is appreciated...

Comment: Why do count fields have letters?

Comment: Just variable representing a number, my example didn't have actual dates, thus don't know what actual number would be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Application,
SUM(IIF([Last Access date]<DateAdd('d',-30,Date()),0,1)) AS Last30Count,
SUM(IIF([Last Access date]<DateAdd('d',-90,Date()),0,1)) AS Last90Count
FROM [TableName]
GROUP BY Application
```

The above has no provision for `NULL` values (it assumes all records are complete) and it counts records not users (so if there are two records with the same user/application combo in the same time period it will be counted twice).